# How do I find where a Series/DataFrame containing intervals overlaps a given interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with price ranges for some items:

```
   price_low  price_high item
0         10          20    a
1          1           7    b
2         10          12    c
3         20          25    d
4          4           8    e
5          5          30    f
6         16          26    g
```

How do I figure out which items overlap a given price range, say $8 - $16?

Expected output:

```
   price_low  price_high item
0         10          20    a
2         10          12    c
4          4           8    e
5          5          30    f
6         16          26    g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of pandas 0.24.0, you can use the [`IntervalArray.overlaps`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.IntervalArray.overlaps.html) method, or alternatively the [`IntervalIndex.overlaps`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.overlaps.html) method:

```
# construct the IntervalArray
price_ivs = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(df['price_low'], df['price_high'], closed='both')

# define desired price Interval and use the overlaps method to restrict df
my_price = pd.Interval(8, 16, closed='both')
df = df[price_ivs.overlaps(my_price)]
```

For an interactive demonstration, first construct the example data:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.0rc1'

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'price_low': [10, 1, 10, 20, 4, 5, 16],
   ...:     'price_high': [20, 7, 12, 25, 8, 30, 26],
   ...:     'item': list('abcdefg')
   ...: })

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   price_low  price_high item
0         10          20    a
1          1           7    b
2         10          12    c
3         20          25    d
4          4           8    e
5          5          30    f
6         16          26    g
```

Construct an `IntervalArray` from the `DataFrame`:

```
In [4]: price_ivs = pd.arrays.IntervalArray.from_arrays(
   ...:     df['price_low'], df['price_high'], closed='both')

In [5]: price_ivs
Out[5]: 
IntervalArray([[10, 20], [1, 7], [10, 12], [20, 25], [4, 8], [5, 30], [16, 26]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

Define the desired price `Interval` and use the `overlaps` method to get a boolean indexer:

```
In [6]: my_price = pd.Interval(8, 16, closed='both')

In [7]: idxr = price_ivs.overlaps(my_price)

In [8]: idxr
Out[8]: array([ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])

In [9]: df[idxr]
Out[9]: 
   price_low  price_high item
0         10          20    a
2         10          12    c
4          4           8    e
5          5          30    f
6         16          26    g
```

If you already have a column of prices as intervals (or a `Series` of intervals), you can use the `array` attribute to access the underlying `IntervalArray` and use the same method as above:

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame({'price_ivs': price_ivs, 'item': list('abcdefg')})

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
  price_ivs item
0  [10, 20]    a
1    [1, 7]    b
2  [10, 12]    c
3  [20, 25]    d
4    [4, 8]    e
5   [5, 30]    f
6  [16, 26]    g

In [12]: idxr = df['price_ivs'].array.overlaps(my_price)

In [13]: idxr
Out[13]: array([ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])

In [14]: df[idxr]
Out[14]: 
  price_ivs item
0  [10, 20]    a
2  [10, 12]    c
4    [4, 8]    e
5   [5, 30]    f
6  [16, 26]    g
```

Answer (score 1):

root's answer is general and informative. In case you are looking for a quick solution for simple cases, you could try below

```
df[(df['price_low']<=16)&(df['price_high']>=8)]
```

It's a precondition for two intervals to overlap. It's easier to understand in this way: the lower boundary of the price range (8) should not be higher than price_high and its upper boundary (16) should not be lower than price_low.

Comment: Yes, though it should be noted that your use of `<=` and `>=` are specific to the case where the both intervals are closed on both sides, and would need to be modified if this were not the case, e.g. one is closed on the left side only, other is closed on the right side only.  The `overlaps` method handles this automatically.

Comment: @root thanks for the complement. Yes `overlaps` is doing a better job.